# Does anyone know any information about Mifal Hashas?

Tags: torah-study, organizations

Does anyone here have any information about Mifal Hashas or Dirshu?

1. What is the learning material?
2. When and where are tests?
3. How much do they give?
4. What kinds of tests are they (multiple choice, fill in the blank)?

Are there any other such programs where they give stipends for learning?

Comment: I don't know. But you can ask them directly. Mifal Hashas's contact information is at http://www.dafyomi.co.il/central.htm, though I can't vouch for that page's accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

Dirshu can be reached at either info@kolleldirshu.org or 888-5-DIRSHU

Mifal HaShas can be reached at 718-599-0111, 718-435-3692, 718-436-7790 in the USA. In Israel their number is 03-579-7020