# What should a Jew learn regularly?

Tags: torah-study, adult-learning

**I am wondering what systems of structured Jewish learnings exist or alternatively how to build one. In a broader way what are existing/recognized Jewish learning curriculums or answers to “what should a Jew know/learn regularly”?**

We know some partial answers

- “shnei mikra v’echad targum” - weekly review of the parsha of the week with its commentary (Onkelos / Rashi) - I know some try to learn every year another commentary on a revolving basis (e.g., Ramban, Baal Haturim)
- [daf yomi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daf_Yomi)
- Hitat (Chabad’s Humash, Tehilim, Tanya) - discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17761/the-value-of-the-daily-study-of-chitas-chumash-tehilim-tanya/65281#65281) on MY
- Chabad’s (and others?) [daily learning of Mishne Torah](http://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/default_cdo/jewish/Daily-Study.htm) (1 chapter a day / 3 chapters a day)

**But am I asking in a broader way. What should a Jew know and regularly learn?** The answer is probably a combination of

- Humash: weekly review of parasha and commentary (what about midrash?)
- Tanakh: yearly review of rest of Tanakh
- Oral Law: daf yomi + review all mishna every 1/2/3 years?
- Halakha: regular review of Mishna Brura (e.g., [Dirshu's Daf Yomi b'Halacha](http://www.jpost.com/Israel-News/Dirshu-Torah-study-organization-celebrates-completion-of-first-cycle-of-new-project-394859), see also [here](http://www.dirshu.co.za/))
- Mussar: e.g., review on a revolving cycle of Mesilat Yesharim, Chovot Halelavot, etc.

**What existing systems are you aware of? What are thoughts on this?**

PS. I read ([in his wife's biography](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422612064.html)) that R Chaim Kanievski has his own seder limud, completing every year Talmud Bavli, Talmud Yerushalmi, Nach, Rambam, Shulchan Aruch, Mishnah Berurah, Midrash Rabbah, Midrash Tanchumah, Sifra, Sifri and Tosefta. But I am looking for something for us normal humans...

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59787 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59453 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55459 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45252 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40929 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10916

Comment: @msh210 many thanks for these. In a nutshell, they say to learn gmara and halacha. I am most interested to go to the specifics and see what our rabbanim have suggested, what post yeshiva students do, what this distinguished kahal does. I am struck that, unlike most disciplines taught in universities, we do not have more established "syllabi" of learning

Comment: @mbloch Chabad's full daily program, as you adumbrated, is Chitas, HaYom Yom (a sefer of the Lubavitcher Rebbe) and 1-3 perakim Mishneh Torah and/or a perek of Sefer Hamitzvos. They publish a magazine called Chayenu containing all the texts for the week's learning

Comment: I think this question would be a great deal more answerable if you would circumscribe the types of sources you're interested in hearing from. Are you looking for systems advocated by classical sources? By contemporary organizations / communal structures?

Comment: @IsaacMoses thanks for this - I am really interested by any answer - classical sources don't have much I found beyond 1/3, 1/3, 1/3 - but maybe I am not aware. "Modern sources" might have more to contribute. I am really completely open. Thanks !

Comment: related: [What is good mussar should one learn daily?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/123839/11501)

Comment: @mbloch - don't forget to mention about Rav Chaim's annual learning regimen that when it's a leap year, he uses the extra month to write a sefer!!!!

Comment: special case of a soldier at war: https://www.torahmusings.com/2023/10/what-torah-should-a-soldier-learn/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the most general sense, one is required to know the entire Torah, meaning both written and oral, revealed and hidden, each individual according to their unique capacity. It is an occupation which lasts over the entire course of ones physical life and beyond.

A very good English explanation of what one should learn regularly can be found at the following link. The main principles are there.

http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Laws_of_Learning_Torah

It is important to note that in terms of actual practice, one should distinguish between someone who has been raised from the beginning according to the these requirements and someone who comes to learning later in life. The general rule for someone who starts later is to divide their study into thirds. This is discussed in detail by the Alter Rebbe in Hilchot Talmud Torah from Shulchan Aruch HaRav.

Particularly for someone who comes to learning later in life, they should pursue those areas where their personal interests are strongest. It doesn't mean to ignore other areas of Torah, but to develop the habit of learning regularly. This means ideally to set aside specific time, however long, each day, once in the morning and once at night when one will be occupied in Torah study. The emphasis is not on volume. It is on regularity.

If reading in Hebrew is preferred, this link is to Hilchot Talmud Torah from the Shulchan Aruch HaRav. The actual text runs from page 67 through 88 of the online document. An introduction precedes it and voluminous explanatory notes follow it.

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16009&st=&pgnum=67&hilite=

And these remaining links provide the continuation and completion of those explanatory notes to text.

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16073&st=&pgnum=1

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16061&st=&pgnum=1

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16070&pgnum=1

Comment: Alternative link for the shulchan aruch harav http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/1/index.htm and http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/ka5/12/index.htm

Comment: @YaacovDeane Many thanks. Still interesting that only general guidelines are provided in Halachipedia (1/3 Torah, 1/3 Mishna/Gmara, 1/3 Halakha) or my preferred quote "Someone who only has 2 or 3 hours to learn daily should learn Halacha from Shulchan Aruch [...] this is more preferable than learning Daf Yomi". Maybe the lack of specifics is, as you say, to follow once' interests. Still I feel we could go deeper in reviewing specific guidance given by great teachers, as an inspiration to others. Still have to review SA HaRav !

Comment: @mbloch, If you're thinking about this for a particular individual, this is part of what the function of a Mashpiah is meant to be. The Mashpiah (literally 'the one who influences') knows the particular individual's character and is able to advise them in detail. Think of a Mashpiah as a sort of 'Spiritual Guidance Counselor'.

Comment: `one is required to know the entire Torah, meaning both written and oral, revealed and hidden, each individual according to their unique capacity` Source? This [does not appear to be Rambam's opinion](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71125/8775) nor is it mentioned AFAIK by the Rif, Rosh, Tur, or Shulhan Arukh.

Comment: `Particularly for someone who comes to learning later in life, they should pursue those areas where their personal interests are strongest. It doesn't mean to ignore other areas of Torah, but to develop the habit of learning regularly. This means ideally to set aside specific time, however long, each day, once in the morning and once at night when one will be occupied in Torah study. The emphasis is not on volume. It is on regularity.` Source?

Comment: Dear Yaacov - Thank you once again for your answer to my "One Jewish Practice" request. I think of your answer and links daily much to my benefit and with much appreciation. Following SAH's suggestion, I am learning Mishnah Yomit, as the name implies - daily. I consider you a hassid in the most complimentary sense of the word (hope I don't embarrass you), not only from your picture, but much more so from how you participate here. In the context of this question, perhaps you might recommend a mussarish text (or portion there of) that I might study. Best personal regards,

Comment: @user18223 Thank you for your kind words. Because of the disadvantage of not knowing you better on a personal level, your background & education, my recommendations would be only general. You could try learning Likkutei Amarim Tanya by the Alter Rebbe each day. If it’s your 1st time, start with the 2nd section, Chinuch Katan/Shaar HaYichud. When you have completed that, start at the title page at the book’s beginning & go straight through each page until the end of section 1. Then go to Igeret HaTeshuvah. That’s a good beginning.

Comment: It is interesting that you link to the Alter Rebbi's words. I was always fascinated by his incredibly rigorous prescription for chazarah. Basically, make sure you never forget a thing, and never move on until you can protect every single thing you've learned. I hear, but wow. Does anyone actually do that?

Comment: @MichoelR Chazorah is extremely important. That theme is not just by the Alter Rebbe. It’s found in HaYom Yom repeatedly but in a way that isn’t obvious. Like memorizing Mishnayot or Tehillim so you can say them during your free moments during the day. It’s called purifying the atmosphere. And it isn’t limited. The impact on one’s self & surroundings is immeasurable.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Yes, but you did not answer my question. We all acknowledge that chazarah is extremely important, but I wonder if someone follows the Alter Rebbe's specific prescription.

Comment: @MichoelR Each individual according to their unique capacity and to the best of their ability.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Don't mean to be troublesome, but that qualifies as a No. The Shulchan Aruch Harav was extremely clear and specific: You may not learn any new Torah until you have made sure that you will not lose your hold on every single thing you've learned till now. Till then, all you do is review. I think that's what he said.

Comment: @MichoelR Please don't put words in my mouth. I say what I mean and I didn't mean "No." Do I believe that there are people today striving to actually do what the Alter Rebbe requires in Shulchan Aruch HaRav in regard to Torah study? Yes.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Don't mean to say too much, not at all. But I would like to know if you could name someone who tries to do that literally. It always struck me as almost a Midrash: Something to strive for, but something you obviously cannot do in any organized learning program. Like, I assume that Chabad yeshivos do nothing of the sort? Is that true, and is it allowable? Anyhow, just wondering.

Comment: @YaacovDeane This is interesting enough to me that maybe I'll turn it into a standalone question.

Comment: @MichoelR If you  are going to post a stand alone question, my suggestion would be that you pose your question by direct quote in the original language and specific page citation of the exact wording from the Alter Rebbe. Not your "free translation" into English like found in your comment above. It is possible that you are misunderstanding the original language.

Comment: @YaacovDeane, as I said in the post, I didn't have access to a digital text. It was a lot of typing, and the translation was most urgent. I'll add the text in with the translation now that I have one.

Comment: @MichoelR It might be easier to go to Hebrewbooks.org, go to the exact page you have a question on in their digital text and take a screenshot. You can upload the screenshot in your question. A link to their specific page would be good too. Think outside the box and make your life easier.

Answer (score 6):

I had the privilege to discuss this question in person with [R Ephraim Buchwald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephraim_Buchwald) who founded/leads the [National Jewish Outreach Program](http://njop.org/) and has personally directly taught thousands of Jews and indirectly hundreds of thousands through his teaching programs.

His answer was

- [*Parsha hashavua* with Rashi](http://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/torahreading.htm)
- the rest of Tanakh
- gemara
- Halakha, e.g., [Rambam's daily study of Mishne Torah](http://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/rambam_cdo/jewish/1-Chapter-a-Day.htm)
- Jewish philosophy, e.g., the [Kuzari](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1583308423), R Kook, R Soloveichik
- Jewish history, e.g., we discussed [R Berel Wein](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1422615111), [Paul Johnson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060915331), or [understanding the history of the day](http://www.aish.com/dijh/)
- Possibly hassidut, e.g., Tanya

He commented on the importance of learning biblical Hebrew and in particular Hebrew grammar (*dikduk*) in order to understand the original text.

Comment: For further reference, see R Kook's Orot HaTorah 9:6, Spiritual revolution of R Kook pp. 26-27, where he writes every Jew has a particular makeup and should not force himself to a rigid curriculum but focus his efforts on the parts of Torah that inspire and excite us without giving up the rest completely.

Answer (score 4):

R Yehuda Greenwald wrote a small booklet called "Torah study" under the direction of R Shlomo Wolbe (I have it in French, it is part of [this](http://www.torah-box.com/editions/guide-de-la-techouva_154.html) larger book).

He suggests there a daily program for working people

- Humash: one *alya* from the daily *parasha* with Rashi
- Halakha: Orach Chaim
- Gemara: (before that to cover all six orders of the Mishna) then major focus on gemara
- Emuna (he names Kuzari, Derekh Hashem, Daat Tvunot, Sefer Haikarim, Nefesh HaChaim)
- Musar (he names Shaarei Tshuva, Chovot Halevavot, Mesilat Yesharim, R Yona on Pirkei Avot and Mishlei or more recent works such as Michtav me-Eliyahu, [Lev Eliyahu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elyah_Lopian), Or Yahel, [Sihot Mussar](https://www.abebooks.com/first-edition/Sichos-Mussar-Sihot-Musar-Reb-Chaims/8074202232/bd) from R [Chaim Leib Shmuelevitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Leib_Shmuelevitz), [Ale Shur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Wolbe) ) or Hassidut as per the individual's preference

He writes the proportions depend on the individual but someone who would only have an hour a day should primarily focus on halacha, from two hours and on he recommends 50-60% of the time dedicated to gemara, the rest to the other disciplines.

Finally he insists on the importance of getting advice from a learned rav that knows the person well.

Comment: The Steipler Gaon writes (Karyana D'Iggarta 2:1) that the first *masechtot* to cover should be Seder Moed, Brachot, Chullin and Niddah

Answer (score 3):

The Alei Shor written by Rav Volbe outlines 4 things every Jew should have 'in their back pocket':

The first he says, is to know clearly all of Shulchan Aruch Mishnah Berurah.

The second thing he says, to secure inside yourself the Chumash, with a wide understand of Rashi and Ramban.

The third thing he says is to acquire a firm grip on Pirkei Avos with the commentary of specifically Rabeinu Yonah (he says that no other commentary's word come so close to the heart as Rabeinu Yonah's).

The fourth and final thing he says, is to acquire a firm grip on the Mesilas Yesharim. With these 4 things, a son of Yisrael can become the image of a "True Jew" (יהודי האמיתי).

Comment: "the first he says, is to know clearly all of Shulchan Aruch Mishnah Berurah." Do you mean both the ShA and the MB? The latter only covers a small fraction of the former.

Comment: for more on the same, see [here](https://www.breslev.co.il/articles/breslevpedia/rabbi_shlomo_wolbe.aspx?id=1240&language=english) section "Alei Shur as a guide", which incidentally answers the previous comment by saying all of Mishna Brura

Comment: Of course, this is not the Alei Shur's "learning program". As you say, it's a separate list of things that a Jew needs to know very well. For instance, he also talks about a program taking a few years to become familiar with Shas.

Answer (score 1):

A great learning program to finish the entire Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in one year can be found here: https://kitzuryomi.org/ Kitzur Shulchan Aruch pretty much covers all the Halachos a Frum Yid NEEDS to know

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: When I first became frum, reading the whole Kitzur was one of the main things I did. I've always been glad I did, and I've tried to encourage my kids to do the same.