# Do you have to know kol ha Torah kula?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, torah-study

Is there a requirement for a Jewish man to know the whole Torah (including every gemara, tosafot, Midrasch…) or is it OK to know the Halacha that is relevant to you and then to use the rest of the time to learn those areas in Torah which are interesting for you? If there is such a requirement (to know all the Torah) can someone give me the source for that requirement and also an explanation of why there is a need to learn even those parts which are seemingly not relevant to you?

Comment: @msh210 Thanks for the edit- it reads much better now... +1 on the interesting question. I don't have ordered sources on this, but it seems Chazal do not expect everyone to know everything (echad hamarbeh v'echad ha mamit), and thus one must choose where to focus their efforts.

Comment: are you asking for an average working person or a full time kollel person or what?

Comment: I think this is a dupe?

Comment: @ray Does your job (or lack thereof) affect your obligation in Mitzvot???

Comment: @DoubleAA it affects how much free time you have

Comment: @ray Perhaps but you have the exact same obligation. If you are Oneis for lack of time, so be it.

Answer (score 5):

In codifying the obligation to study Torah, Rambam never delineates any set components of Torah that a person must study (in the first chapter of Hilchot Talmud Torah, in the rest of that section, or anywhere else that I am aware of).

Accordingly, we can infer that there is no obligation to learn "kol haTorah kulah".

This inference is made by Heshy Zelcer as well:

> Studying the entire Torah: Is there a requirement to study the entire Torah including the Written and Oral Law? Rambam clearly expects one to learn all of the Written and Oral Law early on in his learning process, but he does not seem to formalize this obligation.

Source: [Ḥakirah (vol. 2 p. 125)](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%202%20Zelcer.pdf)

However, presumably Rambam would agree that one must learn practical halacha, for otherwise, how would one know how to practice halacha.

The Semag, however, implies that besides for the obligation to learn practical halacha, there is an obligation to study each of the 613 mitzvot. In his introduction to the Positive Commandments in Semag, he writes:

> כבר הקדמתי בספר מצות לא תעשה עניין ספר הזה כי הוא **לידע יסוד המצות על פי הקבלה ולא [כל] חילוקיהם באורך** ויש מצות שאין נוהגים לדורות ולא היו כי אם לפי שעה ואין ראוי למנותם כגון ברכות וקללות דהר גריזים והר עיבל וסיד אבנים גדולות ועשיית המשכן וכיוצא באלו:
>
> ויש מהמון [ה]עם שאומרין מה לנו ולמצות סדר קדשים קל וחומר למצות סדר זרעים ולמצות סדר טהרות לדברים שאין נוהגין בזמן הזה, אל יאמר אדם כן כי המצות אשר צוה אדון העולם יש לידע יסודותיהם אף על פי שאינם צריכין עתה כי על כל המצות נצטוינו ולמדתם אותם (דברים יא, יט) ונאמר (דברים כז, א) שמור את כל המצוה אשר אנכי מצוה אתכם וגומר, ונאמר (ויקרא כב, לא) ושמרתם מצותי ועשיתם אותם...וכן אמרו רבותינו (תו"כ אמור פרק ט ה"ג) ושמרתם זו המשנה ועשיתם זו העשייה. ויש אדם שילמוד כל ימיו ולא יכול להשיג לדעת מצוה אחת כמאמרה בעל פה מחמת אורך הגמרא ופלפולה...

That is, there is an obligation to know the basics of all of the mitzvot - even the ones which may not apply to the learner.

Answer (score 4):

The Shulchan Aruch HaRav writes (in Hilchos Talmud Torah Ch. 1)

> חייב הוא מן התורה לשכור לו מלמד שילמדנו היטב לידע כל התורה שבכתב ושבע"פ כולה.
>
> דהיינו תנ"ך וכל הלכות פסוקות של כל התורה עם הטעמים כי הן הן פירוש התרי"ג מצות שבתורה ודקדוקיהם בכל פרטיהם ואף שיש בהן חלוקי דעות הרי אלו ואלו דברי אלהים חיים **ואפילו המצות שאין נוהגות עכשיו** וגם ללמוד כל דברי חכמים שהסמיכום על מדרש הפסוקים שהן ההגדות שנאמר כי אם שמור תשמרון את כל המצוה הזאת ודרשו חכמים שלא תאמר למדתי הלכות די לי תלמוד לומר כל המצוה למוד הלכות ואגדות ומדרש שהוא התלמוד שמפרש טעמי ההלכות שבמשניות וברייתות ומקורם בדרשות הפסוקים שבתורה וההלכות שאין להן דרשה בפסוקים הן קבלה הלכה למשה מסיני או מסברא והכל ניתן למשה מסיני וכן דברי חכמים שהסמיכום על מדרש הפסוקים שהן ההגדות כמו שדרשו חכמים על פסוק ואתנה לך את לוחות האבן והתורה והמצוה אשר כתבתי להורותם ומכל מקום לימוד ההלכות קודם ללימוד ההגדות.
>
> וכן אמרו חכמי האמת שכל נפש מישראל צריכה לבא בגלגולים רבים עד שתקיים כל התרי"ג מצות במעשה דבור ומחשבה ודיבור ומחשבה הוא לימוד הלכותיהן על דרך שאמרו חכמים על פסוק זאת תורת החטאת וגו' שכל העוסק בתורת חטאת כאילו כו' ועוד אמרו חכמי האמת שכל נפש צריכה לתיקונה לעסוק בפרד"ס כפי מה שהיא יכולה להשיג ולידע וכל מי שיכול להשיג ולידע הרבה ונתעצל ולא השיג וידע אלא מעט צריך לבא בגלגול עד שישיג וידע כל מה שאפשר לנשמתו להשיג מידיעת התורה הן בפשטי ההלכות הן ברמזים ודרשות וסודות כי כל מה שנשמתו יכולה להשיג ולידע מידיעת התורה זהו תיקון שלימותה ואי אפשר לה להתתקן ולהשתלם בצרור החיים את ה' במקורה אשר חוצבה משםקכח בלתי ידיעה זו ולכן אמרו חכמים אשרי מי שבא לכאן ותלמודו בידו כדי שלא יצטרך לבא בגלגול לעולם הזה:
>
> ה ואל יאמר האדם איך אפשר ללמוד כל התורה שבעל פה כולה הרי התורה אין לה קץ ותכלית כמ"ש לכל תכלה ראיתי קץ רחבה מצותך מאד ונאמר ארוכה מארץ מדה וגו' כי באמת ההלכות הנגלות לנו ולבנינו יש להן קץ ותכלית ומספר וכן המדרשים שנתגלו לנו.
>
> רק שהתורה מצד עצמה אין קץ ותכלית אפילו לפשטי דרשותיה הצפונים בה ורבי עקיבא היה דורש על כל קוץ וקוץ תילי תילים של הלכות ולא הגיע לתכלית דרשותיה עדיין וכן אין קץ ותכלית לעומק טעמי ההלכות והפלפול בטעמיהן ובדרשותיהן במדות שהתורה נדרשת ועל ידי זה יתחדשו ג"כ חידושי הלכות לאין קץ ותכלית למי שזוכה לזה אחר שגמר תחלה כל התורה שבעל פה המסורה לנו ונגלות לעין כל כמו שאמרו חכמים ליגמר אינש והדר ליסבר שהוא עיון בעומק הטעמים וכמו שיתבאר:

So

1. One has to "know the whole Torah", though it's not *so* hard ( :) ), one just has to know all 613 commandments with all their details and all the Midrashim
2. Through learning an "impractical" Halacha, one is considered to have fulfilled that Halacha

Comment: Could you either 1) excerpt the relevant pieces of this quote or 2) translate each paragraph as you go? The wall of text is hard to parse...

Comment: Thank you it's the answear to my question. It says there that you have to fullfill all the mitzvot in deed,speech and thought.How can an Israel ever fullfill the mitzvot that are applicable e.g. to the Kohen gadol or is the learning there considered as deed also.

Comment: Re 1: And Tanakh (which seemingly includes how to lain the whole thing; that's what teaching Mikra at 5 meant in the days before printed books with dots)

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Moshe Feinstein (Igros Moshe, Yoreh Deah, I think chelek alef) writes there is a chiyuv to know the entire Torah because of the passuk ve'shinantam le'vanechah, sheyiheyu divrei torah mechdadin bephichah she'im yishalchah adam al tegamgem ve'tomar lo elo emor lo miyad.

Which by the way Reb Moshe personified.

I am not sure what the definition of the entire Torah is though, can it be that this is increasing exponentially?

Comment: Even Igros Moshe, Yoreh Deah, chlelek alef is a pretty sizable work. Please try and [edit] in a more precise source reference.

Answer (score 3):

Rav Chaim Vital in Hakdamah to "Shaar Hamitsvot" and also in "Shaar Hagilgulgim" writes that a soul descends in to this world to learn all the PaRDeS.And if a soul was not zoche to learn all the Torah this soul should come to this world one more time because of this reason.

Comment: Nice! Moishele, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your first answer! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Comment: But do you have an actual obligation? does it include "every gemara, tosafot, Midrasch"? If there is such a requirement what is the source? Just pointing out points tht could be added to improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd like to point out that there's no end to Torah (see just about any cheesy reason for why the Gemara starts on Daf Beis), so it's physically impossible to know kol haTorah kulah anyway.

What I can tell you is that the Gemara in Kiddushin (30a-ish) darshens the passuk of v'shinantem l'vanecha as v'shilashtem and advises one to divide his days three ways - one part Chumash, one part Mishnayos, and one part Gemara. Most poskim (as per the footnotes in the Artscroll there) seem to agree that Talmud Bavli, which includes all three, fulfills this directive.

We also find in many places (for instance, Rashi at the beginning of this week's Parshah of Bechukosai) that one should toil in Torah in order to fulfill it, which implies that one should learn for practical use, not just for the geshmak that comes out of learning.

What you do with this information is up to you, but it sounds to me like one should be learning Gemaras and Poskim that he can apply to his day-to-day life.

Comment: It seem that the question assumed some set amount "every gemara, tosafot, Midrasch…". The word Torah can mean different things in different contexts. It seem that in the context of this question it refers to a set amount.

Comment: The Gemara Kiddushin addresses the requirement to study each component each day. Some poskim indeed state that the Talmud fulfills this. However, that does not tell us whether or not there is an obligation to know them; just that they need not be studied each day.

Answer (score 0):

The Midrash Mishlei (10, cited by Beiur Halachah, 155) supports the Shulchan Aruch HaRav's position that one must know *kol ha-Torah kulah*:

> אמר ר' ישמעאל בוא וראה כמה קשה יום הדין שעתיד הקב"ה לדון את כל העולם
>   כולו בעמק יהושפט בזמן שתלמידי חכמים באים לפניו אומר לכל אחד מהם כלום
>   עסקת בתורה, אמר לו הן, אומר לו הקב"ה הואיל והודית אמור לפני מה שקרית,
>   ומה ששנית בישיבה, ומה ששמעת בישיבה, מכאן אמרו כל מה שקרא אדם יהא תפוש
>   בידו, ומה ששנה כמו כן, שלא תשיגהו בושה ליום הדין...בא לפניו מי שיש
>   בידו מקרא ואין בידו משנה, הקב"ה הופך את פניו ממנו, ושרי גיהנם מתגברים
>   בו כזאבי ערב, ונוטלין אותו ומשליכין אותו לתוכה. בא לפניו מי שיש בידו
>   שני סדרים או שלשה, אז הקב"ה אומר לו בני כל ההלכות למה לא שנית אותם,
>   ואם אומר הקב"ה הניחוהו, מוטב, ואם לאו עושין לו כמדת הראשון. בא לפניו
>   מי שיש בידו הלכות, הקב"ה אומר לו בני תורת כהנים למה לא שנית, שיש בה
>   טומאה וטהרה, וטומאת שרצים, וטהרת שרצים, טומאת נגעים, וטהרת נגעים,
>   טומאת נתקים ובתים, טהרת נתקים ובתים, טומאת זבים ולידה, וטהרת זבים
>   ולידה, טומאת מצורע וטהרתו, סדר ווידוי יום הכפורים, וגזירות שוות, ודיני
>   ערכים, וכל דין שדנו ישראל לא דנו אלא מתוכו. בא לפניו מי שיש בידו תורת
>   כהנים, אומר לו הקב"ה בני חמשה חומשי תורה למה לא שנית, שיש בהם ק"ש
>   ותפילין ומזוזה. בא לפניו מי שיש בידו חמשה חומשי תורה, אומר לו בני למה
>   לא למדת הגדה ולא שנית, שבשעה שחכם יושב ודורש אני מוחל ומכפר עונותיהם
>   של ישראל...בא לפניו מי שיש בידו הגדה, אומר לו הקב"ה בני תלמוד למה לא
>   שנית שכל הנחלים הולכים אל הים והים איננו מלא (קהלת א ז), זה התלמוד שיש
>   בו חכמות הרבה. בא מי שיש בידו תלמוד, הקב"ה אומר לו בני הואיל ונתעסקת
>   בתלמוד, צפית במרכבה, צפית בגאוה שאין הנייה בעולמי אלא בשעה שתלמידי
>   חכמים יושבים ועוסקים בתורה מציצין ומביטין ורואין והוגין המון התלמוד
>   הזה, כסא כבודי היאך הוא עומד, רגל הראשונה במה היא משמשת, שנייה במה היא
>   משמשת...מכאן היה ר' ישמעאל אומר אשרי תלמיד חכם שהוא משמר תלמודו בידו,
>   כדי שיהא לו פתחון פה להשיב ליום הדין לפני בוראו

Comment: @mevaqesh see above

Comment: You can't ping someone in a comment unless they are either an author, editor, or commenter of the post. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).