# Hierarchy of learning

Tags: torah-study

What is the best way to go about learning the fundamentals of Torah? Obviously the chumash would be first, and gemara seems to take precedence in yeshivot.
So my question is what are the basics one should learn and in what order should it be learned in?

Comment: Refer to Pirkei Avos 5:21 - https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.21?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi - whilst there is a discussion if these ages are still applicable today, it helps at least, to provide a framework of what area of study to progressively move on to.

Comment: You might find this other question relevant: [What should a Jew learn regularly?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66966/11501)

Answer (score 1):

Though Pirkei Avot says students learn Torah, Mishna, and Gemara in that order, that is for children. Most children will have grown up in a Jewish home and would have informally learned "Derech Eretz" and Jewish practices before even opening a book.

So much of Judaism's thoughts and practices are not obviously in the Torah. It would be easier to learn them first and then use that as a context for reading the books.